# Как определить порядковый номер недели года?

Tags: php

Как определить порядковый номер недели года, зная дату в правильном формате?

Например, 12.03.2011: как вытащить из него порядковый номер недели?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Функция [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) умеет:

```
$test = strtotime("12.03.2011"); // тут может преобразование отличаться
echo "week: ".date("W", $test);
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Все четко!

Answer (score 2):

А если не использовать php функции, то как-то так.

```
if((year%4)==0) value = (31*(month-1)-month/2+day)/7;
else{
    if(month>2) day = day-1;
    value = (31*(month-1)-month/2+day)/7;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$data = new DateTime('2016-11-11');
echo $data->format('W');
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.