# Как получить номера всех недель месяца?

Tags: php

Нужно получить номера всех недель месяца и желательно в массиве.

Мне нужно определить не просто номер 1 недели. текущей даты. Мне нужно получить все недели например января 2015. То есть чтобы в массиве было 4 значения недель - 1, 2, 3,4

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как определить порядковый номер недели года?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/6577/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0)

Comment: номер недели в году?

Comment: Мне нужно определить не просто номер 1 недели. текущей даты. 
Мне нужно получить все недели например января 2015. То есть чтобы в массиве было 4 значения недель - 1, 2, 3,4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На скорую руку

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setDate($date->format('Y'), $date->format('m'), 1); // первый день тек. месяца
$firstWeek = (int) $date->format('W'); // первая неделя
$date->setDate($date->format('Y'), $date->format('m') + 1, 0); // последний день тек. месяца
$lastWeek = (int) $date->format('W'); // последняя неделя
$arrWeek = range($firstWeek, $lastWeek); // массив недель тек. месяца
var_dump($arrWeek);
```

Comment: $fd = date("t.".$fdp);
$ld = date("01.".$fdp); 
 
$fw = strtotime($ld);  
$firstWeek = date("W", $fw);
$lw = strtotime($fd); 
$lastWeek = date("W", $lw);
$arrWeek = range($firstWeek, $lastWeek);

Answer (score 0):

```
$test = strtotime("12.03.2011"); // тут может преобразование отличаться
echo "week: ".date("W", $test);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$fd = date("t.".$fdp);
$ld = date("01.".$fdp); 

$fw = strtotime($ld);  
$firstWeek = date("W", $fw);
$lw = strtotime($fd); 
$lastWeek = date("W", $lw);
$arrWeek = range($firstWeek, $lastWeek);
```